# Can multiple signals can be connected to single slot

Tags: c++, qt

**How many signals can be connected to single slot.yes as many we can but how to do that.**

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq10-signalmapper.html

Comment: Is there a specific problem you have encountered, or is this just a general question?

Comment: I went through this url but not get the exact replay

Comment: as Danh answered, the documentation is your best friend

Answer (score 5):

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

> You can connect as many signals as you want to a single slot, and a signal can be connected to as many slots as you need. It is even possible to connect a signal directly to another signal. (This will emit the second signal immediately whenever the first is emitted.)